# Square brackets in axis label

Tags: plotting

Within the Plot[] environment I'd like to label one of the axes as

$r\,\,[a_0]$

with square brackets to denote that $a_0$ is the unit. How can I achieve this? So far I've tried

Text[Style[ToExpression["r [a_0]", TeXForm, HoldForm]]

but this outputs

$r\,\,(a_0)$.

So, the subscript comes out correctly but not the brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `StringForm`:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1},
AxesLabel -> {Text[StringForm["r[``]", Subscript[a, 0]]], Automatic}]
```

It is alternatively possible to enter the subscripts directly inside the quoted string (without using `StringForm`).